How to change the "Pattern not found" message colors in Vim?
When I perform a search for something in vim, if it's not found, the "Pattern not found" message is a light/white color on a light blue background, which is very difficult to read.

How can I change the "Pattern not found" colors? I'm  happy with the rest of the color scheme, I just want to change the colors of this (and potentially other) such notifications.


:help colorscheme-override explains how to override parts of a colorscheme.
The highlight group used for error messages is ErrorMsg, which can be found under :help highlight-groups, where each group name is highlighted according to your current colorscheme.

Therefore, assuming your colorscheme is called foobar:
augroup my_colorscheme_overrides
    autocmd!
    autocmd Colorscheme foobar highlight ErrorMsg ctermbg=red
augroup END

If you want your override to work for every colorscheme, just use a * for the autocommand pattern:
augroup my_colorscheme_overrides
    autocmd!
    autocmd Colorscheme * highlight ErrorMsg ctermbg=red
augroup END

See :help autocommands.
Note that this should come before any colorscheme foobar in your vimrc.

It's the ErrorMsg highlight group.
To see its current definition, enter :hi ErrorMsg. For example, the definition might be ctermfg=15 ctermbg=1 guifg=White guibg=Red.
To change the definition, for example change ctermbg to 2, use :hi ErrorMsg ctermbg=2.
